# Django - handling form without the form model

Tags: python, django, forms

I wish to handle a form I created with HTML in django, but I can't find the correct way to get the value from the inputs.

This is my HTML form:

```
<form action="" class="form-inline" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    <!-- malfunction description -->
    <label class="requiredField" for="malfunctionDescription">תאור
        התקלה</label>
    <br/>
    <textarea class="form-control" style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 3px"
              id="malfunctionDescription"
              name="malfunctionDescription"
              rows="5">
     </textarea>
</form>
```

And this is my view.py which is unfortunately empty:

```
def index(request):
error = ''
if request.method == 'POST':
    status = request.POST['status']
    rank = request.POST['rank']
    opener = request.POST['MalfunctionOpener']
    handler = request.POST['malfunctionHandler']
    system = request.POST['system']
    unit = request.POST['unit']
    opening_date = request.POST['openingdate']
    closing_date = request.POST['closingdate']
    description = request.POST['malfunctionDescription']
    solution = request.POST['malfunctionSolution']
    summary = request.POST['malfunctionSummary']

    find_description = Malfunction.objects.filter(description=description)
    if find_description:
        error = 'This malfunction is already stored in the data base'
    else:
        Malfunction.objects.create(status=status, rank=rank, opener=opener, handler=handler, system=system,
                                   unit=unit, openingDate=opening_date, closingDate=closing_date, solution=solution,
                                   summary=summary, description=description)

else:
    error = 'Something went wrong'

return render(request, 'resources-management/home.html')
```

The main goal for me is to get this information from the form and create a new object that will push it to the data base.
If I understand correctly to create this object I need to do something like:

```
Object_name.object.create(information=information)
```

But I don't know how to get the information, I need something like **request.form['name']** in Flask

Thanks!

---- EDIT 1 - url.py ----

This is the main url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^', include('elbit_ils.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^resources-management/', include('resources_management.urls')),
url(r'^registration-login/', include('registration_login.urls')),
url(r'^contact/', include('contact.urls')),
```

]

This is the application url.py

`urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view(), name="my_list"),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$', DetailView.as_view(model=Malfunction, template_name="resources-management/malfunction.html")),
]`

-- edit 2 : indexview --

class IndexView(CreateView):

```
context_object_name = 'my_list'
template_name = 'resources-management/home.html'
queryset = Malfunction.objects.all()
fields = '__all__'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['contacts'] = Contact.objects.all().order_by("firstname")
    context['malfunctions'] = Malfunction.objects.all().order_by("-openingDate")
    context['systems'] = System.objects.all().order_by("systemname")
    context['units'] = Unit.objects.all().order_by("unitname")
    # And so on for more models
    return context
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a form like

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Note the `name` attribute in `input` element. Then

In `django`, you will get data in `request.POST`.So you can do

```
request.POST['username']
```

Comment: For some unknown reason I get this Method Not Allowed (POST): /my_url/ any ideas why??

Comment: Please post your url.py, full view, whether DEBUG is True or False?

Comment: I've added the url.py, The debug set to true

Comment: You posted one view named index.But it is not use in urls.py

Comment: it is the index view, I've just edit the main question again the code

Comment: `ListView` is not indented to do `post` request. You should check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview

Comment: any recommendations what should I use instead?

Comment: `UpdateView` for `update`, `CreateView` for `create` objects.

Comment: OK great, so I managed everything, I send the information I get back to the page I was in, no errors appears. But also no object created, I have edited the main post again with the code

Comment: Thank you! Just because I was missing the name attribute, none of my form data was being passed into request.POST.

Comment: I am getting django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'description'

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access the data in the following way

```
def index(request):
    # All the post data is stored in `request.POST`
    desc = request.POST["malfunctionDescription"]
```

You can look at how to use [Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/) in the docs, to learn the best way to validate the data you receive.

Answer (score 0):

For Django version 4.0.1(Basically secured versions) you have to use csrf_token.

Example:
In my_app/templates/my_app/index.html

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="x" placeholder="x values" title="Enter x values">
    <input type="submit" value="Enter">
</form>
```

In my_app/views.py

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        x_val = request.POST['x']
        return HttpResponse(x_val)
    return render(request,'plots/index.html')
```